Unable to install symfony/amqp-messenger due to amqp issue
I've been trying to set up the PHP AMQP extension on WAMP server with PHP 8.2. I've placed rabbitmq.4.dll, and rabbitmq.4.pdb in the PHP root and php_amqp.dll in the ext folder. However, I keep encountering this error when I try to run PHP from the command line:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp' (tried:
c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.0/ext/amqp (The specified module could not be
found), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.0/ext/php_amqp.dll (The specified
module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

I've added extension=amqp/extension=php_amqp.dll to php.ini, but it hasn't resolved the issue. The strange part is, when I check through the browser or locally, I can see php_amqp.dll listed in the extensions directory. Interestingly, the AMQP extension works fine when accessed through Apache, as confirmed by phpinfo(). It shows that AMQP is loaded in WAMP's GUI, but it doesn't work in CLI.
In Apache's php.ini, extension=php_amqp.dll works perfectly, but not in CLI. Has anyone successfully configured PHP 8.2 with AMQP on WAMP, especially in CLI mode?

Do you see your extension when you php -m ?

Are you sure c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.0/ext/php_amqp.dll exists?

Check this out - https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/install-windows#:~:text=Once%20a%20supported%20version%20of,it%20using%20the%20default%20configuration. if manually -> https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/install-windows-manual

@hassan no when I run php -m I get this error Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.0/ext/amqp (The specified module could not be found), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.0/ext/php_amqp.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

@Olivier yes php_amqp.dll is there. In apache it is working but in cli mode it;s not.
